Does a mourner during shiva omit the "Titkabel" verse from Kaddish Shalem?
My recollection from when I sat shiva for my father (z"l) is that if an avel is the shaliach tzibbur in a shiva house, he omits the verse "titkabel" from the final Kaddish Shalem.  I remember seeing this instruction in the siddur for the house of mourning that was provided for our use by the local funeral home. I always assumed that this was related to the fact that "titkabel" is omitted on Tisha b'Av, and that it is not included in the Kaddish Yatom.
However, at a shiva house this evening none of the other people present were aware of this custom, and I could find no mention of it in either the Artscroll or the Koren siddur.  Now I'm wondering if I am misremembering, or if I hallucinated the whole thing.  (For what it's worth, at the time I sat shiva we were using a Conservative siddur, not an Orthodox one, so perhaps this is something specific to Conservative practice.)
Can anybody enlighten me on whether this is an actual practice, and (if so) whether it is limited only to certain communities or if it is more generally observed? Sources are appreciated.
Edited: Shortly after posting this question I found the following on the OU website:

Although some have the custom to omit the "titkabel" passage from the final kaddish recited at the end of services in a shiva house, it is reported that Rabbi Moshe Feinstein was very against this practice and insisted that the final kaddish be recited in its entirety as normal.

This seems to both confirm that the custom exists while simultaneously arguing against it. It does not, however, provide any sources for where this custom comes from, who follows it, and whether there are any other respected poskim who hold differently than Rabbi Feinstein, so I would still appreciate any information that can be provided.
